# Fuerza bruta en PowerShell archivo .asc

Tags: powershell

tengo un archivo realizado con PGP v.10 con extensión .asc que al ejecutarlo automáticamente me sale para colocar la contraseña, diseñe un script en PowerShell para que automáticamente abriera el archivo y mediante un txt me  leyera las posibles contraseñas pero no he podido lograrlo, les agradecería su inmensa ayuda muchas gracias.

[image: captura al momento de abrir el archivo]

El código PS es:

```
    $archivo_txt = Get-Content "C:\Users\Janus\Desktop\PgpPython\pass.txt"
    $ascPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PGP Corporation\PGP Desktop\PGPdesk.exe"
    $ascFile = "C:\Users\Janus\Desktop\PgpPython\prueba.asc"
    foreach ($password in $archivo_txt)
    {
    Write-Host $password
    & $ascPath "t" $ascFile "-p$password"
    if (-Not $?)
    {
        Write-Host $password "no hay password."
    } else {
        Write-Host $password "este es el password."
    }
}
pause
```

Comment: Qué falla en tu código actual? Qué error sale? Decir "no me funciona" suele ser una mala idea porque nadie sabrá qué está sucediendo (y así ayudar a corregirlo). Por favor, EDITA tu pregunta y añade más información sobre lo que dices que falla

Comment: si señor es que lee lo que hay grabado en el txt pero no ejecuta la contraseña por ende el programa no logra incluirlo, pero si lo hago manual si lo realiza.

Comment: Posiblemente usar la interfaz GUI de PGP no es el camino, pues no es trivial que PS le cambie parámetros (cómo debería PS poner un texto en un campo de un formulario gráfico?). Podrías probar usando un ejecutable de PGP por línea de comandos

Comment: si señor voy a intentarlo muchas gracias por su ayuda.